# Dynamic dropdown in Spring boot by retrieving data from MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, reactjs, spring-boot, rest

As a beginner to spring boot I try to do dynamic dropdown in spring boot by retrieving data from MySQL database and using that dropdown in react by using rest api. how I can do dynamic dropdown for my application which filtering data in a single table column by column and fetch to react.

I tried several methods but there using multiple entities/tables. Can I done it with single entity/table

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This question is very ambiguous but anyway if you want to achieve your goal its better to use spring data .
First add this dependency in your pom file

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

for example you have an entity named Customer like this

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Customer {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=...)
private Long id;

private String name;
private String lastaName;

}
```

and then This is your repository interface where you can write your filter queries
Like bellow

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer , Long> {

List<Customer> findByName(String name);
Customer findByNameAndLastName(String name,string lastName);
}
```

And you have to create a service class like bellow

```
public class CustomerService {

private final CustomerRepository repository;

@Autowired
public CustomerService( CustomerRepository repository){

this.repository = repository;
}

public List<Customer> findCustomersByName(String name){
 return repository.findByName(name);
}

public Customer findByNameAndLastName(String name , String lastName) {
 return repository.findByNameAndLastName(name, lastName);
}
}
```

And then your controller must be like bellow

```
@RestController
public class CustomerController {

private finale CustomerService service;

public CustomerController( CustomerService service) {
 this.service = service;
}

@GetMapping( value = "/get-by-name" )
public ResponseEntity<?> findByName(@RequestParam String name){
 return ResponseEntity.ok(service.findByName(name);
}

@GetMapping( value = "/get-by-name-and-lastName" )
public ResponseEntity<?> findByNameAndLastName(@RequestParam String name ,@RequestParam String lastName){
 return ResponseEntity.ok(service.findByNameAndLastName(name , lastName);

}
```